# Why is this question off topic? (EMC on DC supply cable)

Tags: discussion

I asked [this question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/199730/emc-problem-with-dc-supply-cable) and want to know why it's been voted for closing. The topic is surely about electrical engineering: how to diagnose and solve an electronics/electrical problem?

How could it have been altered to satisfy requirements for this site?

Comment: "Questions on the use of electronic devices are off-topic as this site is intended specifically for questions on electronics design."

Comment: I can see that argument, but at the same time I see no reason why it doesn't also fit in the on-topic list. I honestly think there's a flaw in the system; if a question can be construed as both off and on topic, it gets closed anyway

Answer (score 0):

You question starts off with:

> The scenario: I've had a nightmare putting up a wifi/ethernet CCTV camera. My other half has developed a truly psychopathic enemy and we need this up.

I didn't see your question originally, but I would have stopped there and voted to close as being a consumer use of electronics question, not about electrical engineering.  Perhaps the rest of the question does get into some specific electrical engineering issues, but I'll never know.  If the question had been shorter and more to the point I might read on, but not when there's over a screen of text to wade thru.  So I think to myself *screw this*, close for the nearest handy reason, and move on to something more productive.